# Implementing Spring Security with Struts 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, struts2, action-mapping

I want to implement Spring Security + Struts2

I had a problem when I execute my project :

> There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [j_spring_security_check] associated with context path [/Project]
>   because there is no action named 'j_spring_security_check' in struts.xml

How can I resolve this? This is the code for `Login.jsp`

**Login.jsp**

```
<form action="/j_spring_security_check" method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="ID Utilisateur" name="j_username" autofocus>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Mot de passe" name="j_password">
    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i>   Se Connecter</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form action should be handled by spring security before the struts filter. Make sure the order of filters is the following

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```